# searchBar has trouble filtering swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Okay, I hope this is going to make sense:

So what I'm trying to do is filter usernames into the collectionView that I get from firebase. I have it all set up, it fetches the usernames and displays it onto the collection view when I click the search bar. When I start typing on the search bar, it does filter usernames BUT not on the UI.

> The reason for this is **because the search bar and the collectionViews** it shows when clicked **to filter usernames, are in different classes.**

Still don't know what I'm trying to say? Here's what I mean:

[click here for the searchBar & CollectionViewController together picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yux0y.png)

[click here to for the searchBar & collection View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIFqs.png)

UserSearchController with the relevant code:

```
var users = [User]()
func fetchUsers() {
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users")
    ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let dictionaries = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

        //For each iterates through every object in the dictioary
        dictionaries.forEach({ (key, value) in

            guard let userDictionary = value as? [String: Any] else { return}
            let user = User(uid: key, dictionary: userDictionary)
            self.users.append(user)
            print(user.uid, user.username)
        })
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()

    }) { (error) in
        print("failed to fetch users:", error)
    }
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    self.users = self.users.filter { (user) -> Bool in
        print(",here:",user)
        return user.username.contains(searchText)
    }
    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
}
```

UserSearchCV with relevant code:

```
var users = [User]()
func fetchUsers() {

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users")
    ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let dictionaries = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

        //For each iterates through every object in the dictioary
        dictionaries.forEach({ (key, value) in

            guard let userDictionary = value as? [String: Any] else { return}
            let user = User(uid: key, dictionary: userDictionary)
            self.users.append(user)
            print(user.uid, user.username)
        })
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()

    }) { (error) in
        print("failed to fetch users:", error)
    }
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

//let numberOfUsers = UserSearchController.searchBar(users.count) did you mean to use a value of this type instead?
    return users.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! UserSearchCVCell
    //        let filteredUsers = UserSearchController.searchBar(users.count)
    //        cell.user = filteredUsers[indexPath.item]
    cell.user = users[indexPath.item]
    return cell
}
```

The code that has been commented out would be nice but it doesn't let me it compiles an error with 'Instance member 'searchBar cannot be used on type 'UserSearchController'.

**var users = User** sample data:

```
struct User {
let uid: String
let username: String
let profileImageUrl: String
let videos: String
init(uid: String, dictionary: [String: Any]) {
    self.uid = uid
    self.username = dictionary["username"] as? String ?? ""
    self.profileImageUrl = dictionary["profileImageUrl"] as? String ?? ""
    self.videos = dictionary["Videos"] as? String ?? ""
}
```

}

Let me know if you have any questions with understanding the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Please explain "it does filter usernames BUT not on the UI" and in image you say "doesnt want to filter when typing" ?

Comment: @3stud1ant3 Sure. What I tried to say there is that it prints the filtering occurred in the  "textDidChange" method when typing. But the collection views doesn't filter at all. It stays the same like if nothing was happening

Comment: Also please explain the difference between two images that you showed, so  I can understand the flow of your app or are they same?

Comment: Okay. So in the first image, the searchBar and the collection view is in the class called "UserSearchController". And in the second image, that's what is shown when you click the searchBar. Now, the purpose for that was to show that the searchBar and the collectionView to show users are two different classes.

Comment: @3stud1ant3 The collectionView to show the users is in the 'UserSearchCV' class. Not in the "UserSearchController" class. So if you see above in the code that I've provided, some code is commented out because that's what I would like to do but it's not possible.

Comment: So what I have understood is this: You only want to set the users array of UserSearchCV from UserSearchController with the filtered array that you get through this code self.users = self.users.filter { (user) -> Bool in
        print(",here:",user)
        return user.username.contains(searchText)
    }, am I right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153088/discussion-between-erik-batista-and-3stud1ant3).

Comment: Try to set UserSearchCV.users not self.users in `textDidChange`

Comment: @ViniApp sure I added it above!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion with OP, we have found a solution

please follow these

first update your searchBar method as follows

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) { 


self.users = self.users.filter { (user) -> Bool in 
print(",here:",user) 
delegate?.passFilterArray(self.users) 
return user.username.contains(searchText) 

} 
searchUsersCV.isHidden = true 
searchUsersCV.updateUsersView(self.users) 

self.collectionView?.reloadData() 
}
```

and then in UserSearchCV add this

```
func updateUsersView(_ users: [User]) { 

self.users = users 
print(self.users) 
self.collectionView.reloadData() 
}
```